# No video with supported format and MIME type found in Firefox with HTML5 video

Tags: video, insert, dreamweaver

I'm trying to insert a video, using HTML5.

I have the following markup:

```
<video id="video" loop="" controls="" preload="">
    <source src="portada_2.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <source src="portada_2.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
</video>
```

but when I open the page in Firefox, it shows me the following message:

> No video with supported format and MIME type found

It only works in CHROME..

www.juanypinchame.es

I've changed the permissions in htaccess..

I have no idea how I can properly configure Server MIME Types..

Thanks a lot

doesn´t work...
how can acess to the htaccess in the cpanel?
someone, told me to write something about mime type on the htaccess..i dont know how.

Comment: Please don't link to your sites. If you would like, please provide a link to something like jsfiddle or codepen in order to show your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Add the lines below to your .htaccess in the root directory

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use standard MIME types.

```
MIME Types for Video Formats. 

MP4  -video/mp4
WebM -video/webm
Ogg  -video/ogg
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: this is not a solution, sorry