# HTML5 video not working in any browser

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I found other posts here for the same issue, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424729/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found-what-does-this-mean-and-how) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604949/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found-in-firefox-with-html5-video) but I wasn't able to solve my issue.
At first, I run below javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = JSON.stringify({'maxSize': 320, 'videoQuality': 6, 'noaudio': true});
    ogg.encode(options);
</script>
```

Then I have below html:

```
<video id="video1" width="500" controls="controls" >
    <source src="Rio2Trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="Rio2Trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
    <source src="Rio2Trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
    The browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

I tried adding

```
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

to the .htaccess file(which was empty) but no success.

On Firefox, i get the message:

> No video with supported format and MIME type found.

On Chrome, I can just see the controls but they look like they are disabled and I don't see the play button in the middle of the screen as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing HTML5 video can be tricky. There are 3 things to check for:

- check your MP4 files is properly encoded for web delivery. You can try to use [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) or MP4Box or ffmpeg to repack your file. You need to activate the "web optimized" option (aka fast start) with handbrake.
- check your server config: for mime types have a look [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) section "MIME Types Rear Their Ugly Head". Try to restart your Apache server after the changes in config. If it does not work in .htaccess try your site-wide httpd.conf. Other things to check includes CORS and 206 Partial Content/Range Requests
- check your script/HTML5: try a barebone HTML5 video tag in a blank page with your mp4. If it works then scripts in your page may be affecting video playback. You can also check CPU load when playing back full HD videos.

I normally use [videojs mp4 sample](http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4) as a reference for a known working mp4/server config. This applies to mp4 but for webm/ogg as well (you can use [make web video](http://firefogg.org/make/) for transcoding to WebM or Ogg).

Let us know how it goes.