# .mp4 file run in firefox but not render through video tag

Tags: html, firefox, ubuntu, video

Here is the configuration of system I am using

Ubuntu : 12.04

Mozilla Firefox : 26.0

I have a mp4 file, when I open it directly in browser like

```
http://localhost/MyProject/web/video/samples/A001C026_140418WK.mp4
```

It runs in browser properly, but when I try the same file to render through html5 video, it is not getting played and shows below error.

```
 No video with supported format and MIME type found.
```

I know this question is appeared many times but I did not get the clear way to kick this problem, second thing this file is getting played properly using `<embed>` tag.

Video tag syntax

```
<video width="854" height="480" controls>
   <source src="{{asset('video/samples/A001C026_140418WK.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

path specified is correct, I have checked properly.

Please guide, where the things are going wrong or missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to rely in the fact your mime types are not properly configured server side. Have a look here for [set up steps](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#video-mime-types). Make sure you restart/reload your web server for changes to be taken into account

After you have checked that it should work in a HTML5 video tag.

For MP4 H264/AAC to work with Firefox on Linux you need to have GStreamer codecs being installed. But I guess you have that covered. You can find more information in this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) section notes.

You can check this question for [further troubleshooting steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329770/html5-video-not-working-in-any-browser/).