# Embedded webm video freezes in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, freeze

I am making a system that I run on localhost, it embeds a video player and all works fine except for webm videos on Chrome. They freeze regularly and I can only get them running again by pressing play/pause and moving to the initial phases of the video.

I have been googling for this issue and trying to solve it for some time now without success, does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is your same WebM file working ok on Firefox? I assume you are using HTML5 video.

I have compiled a short check list on how to troubleshoot HTML5 video playback issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329770/html5-video-not-working-in-any-browser/). Try to play the videojs [webm sample](http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm) to see if it works.

Given the description of your issue I guess it is either a non proper WebM file or a server side tuning issue (like with mime types).

If it is a file format issue you could try re-transcoding from a known good source (ie not the problematic WebM file) with [firefogg](http://firefogg.org/make/). 
You can also try to set the preload attribute of your HTML5 video tag to auto.

Comment: yes im using html5 video and yes that very same file works in firefox. the thing is that the file is located on an external media, and bizarrely if i move it into my base localhost directory, then all of a sudden it works. but thats problematic as the entire base of video files is located on an external media and must be so in the future.

Comment: Are you using NFS? Could it be that the device/network is busy at the moment of the request? Is there any timeout/throttle between the storage unit and the local web server? Is there any error in the Chrome console? You can check the network tab to see if the file stops downloading. You can deliver HTML5 video with NFS and cross domain. It sounds like an environment issue with your external media.